# ploting the mtry and n_tree values along with the accuracy

Tags: r, plot, random-forest

i have to plot the ntree and mtry hyperparameter vlues along with accuracy on the graph with all 3 values and find out the intersection value of this 3 to finalise the optimum values within the range that am passing

```
for(i in seq(1,100))
{    
    ntried[i]<-i
    for (j in seq(1,10)) 
    {
    mtried[j]<-j    
    rf_mod1 <- randomForest(target~., data = heartdb, ntree = 
    ntried[i] , mtry= mtried[j] , importance= TRUE )

    t<-predict(rf_mod1,data = heartdb)
    p<-table(actual =heartdb$target, prediction = t )
    accuracy[i]<-sum(diag(p))/sum(p)

   }
}
```

Comment: why do you need to plot it? you want to maximize accuracy, right? `which(accuracy == max(accuracy))`

Comment: yes i want to maximize with known combination of mtry and ntree plus the visual graph too fir just exploration

Comment: We don't have your data and don't know what packages you're using (several packages have functions `randomForest`) to be able to run your code, and we can't see any output, so all we can do is guess until there's a complete example. Please reread [ask]

Answer (score 2):

As written your loop won't work, you're going to instead be capturing random forests each having tried 10 trees. Try this instead

```
accuracy <- matrix(rep( 0, times = 1000), ncol = 10)
for(i in seq(1,100))
{    
    ntried <- i
    for (j in seq(1,10)) 
    {
    mtried <- j    
    rf_mod1[j] <- randomForest(target~., data = heartdb, ntree = 
    ntried , mtry= mtried , importance= TRUE )

    t<-predict(rf_mod1,data = heartdb)
    p<-table(actual =heartdb$target, prediction = t )
    accuracy[i,j]<-sum(diag(p))/sum(p)
   }

}
```

Now each row of accuracy contains 10 accuracies. By row, search for the maximum:

```
apply(accuracy, 1, max)
```

You can even plot the maximum per level of `ntried`:

```
plot(seq(1,100), apply(accuracy, 1, max))
```

Lastly, you can call the following to return the row (level of ntried) that contains the maximum accuracy for all 1000 forests:

```
which(apply(accuracy, 1, max) == max(apply(accuracy, 1, max)))
```

Comment: i just want the column index for the highest value for the row index in all 1000th

Comment: a13<-apply(accuracy, 2, max) 
 which(apply(accuracy, 2, max) == max(apply(accuracy, 2, max)))

Comment: I see. yes, you can do `apply(accuracy, 1, function(x) which(x == max(x)))` to return a single vector that contains in it the column index that was the maximum of row `i`, to `nrow(accuracy)`